# How do human cells respond to mechanical pressure such as heel contact during walking?

Tags: cell-biology, energy, membrane-transport

Basically, I'd like to do a full accounting (inventory, assets, liabilities) of a human cell under mechanical pressure.

For example, if in steady-state, does the cell consume more or less energy under pressure?

Is membrane transport affected? For example are ion gradients or cell fluid levels changed in response to pressure. If there is a change, how does the cell sustain this over a period of time.

Conversely, if a gradient is disturbed by mechanical pressure, what are the energetic consequences? Does the system behave like a spring such that if the concentration gradients are perturbed out of balance, there is a restoring force (say passive) that will rebalance after the mechanical pressure is removed?

Any focused sources or references would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the difference between a cell's inventory and a cell's assets in this context?